# Contact form - attachment for autorespond

Tags: php, attachment, contact-form, auto-responder

I have an contact form which is to be filled and data send to  my mail. As I don't know much about php I am here seeking any advice what how to make it responding with the attachment to the person who filled a form. I mean someone who filled out the form will receive confirmation email with some pdf attachment.

Thanks for help!!!

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "website@email.com";
$EmailTo = "myemail@gmail.com";
$Subject = "www.davidstekly.com contact form";
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])); 
$Tel = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Tel'])); 
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email'])); 
$Message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $Tel;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $Email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $Message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");


// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the actual question ?

Comment: this script is able to send details of a person who filled out the form to me and I would like to ask how to make it also responding to the person who filled it and also add the attachment to that response. Simple send out a brochure to someone who filled it out.